# Use non-ASCII characters as password(or UTF-8 password) in <input type="password" />

Tags: html, utf-8, passwords

Is there any way to input non-ascii characters, e.g. Russian characters or CJK glyphs, in password field in HTML? That would greatly enhance the password strength!

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289847/can-i-set-these-char-as-password/4289869#4289869

Answer (score 1):

it would if the thing on the other end of the password accepted non-ascii characters.  Heck, most places still don't allow you to use non-alphanumeric ascii characters yet...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, if page declares appropriate encoding and server is able to process it.

In this respect `<input type=password>` isn't any different than `<input type=text>`.

One thing to keep in mind is that in Unicode same character can sometimes be represented in different ways, e.g., Å can be either a single code-point (U+00C5) or combination of regular A and ˚ (U+02DA).

Because of this seemingly-identical passwords may be different to the application, frustrating users. You'd need to normalize Unicode before hashing the password.